# w3schools modal images don't work in Chrome using polymer web-components

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component

I pasted the html/css/javascript code from the modal image [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) to one of my pages and when I click on that image the modal image dialog doesn't get opened. 
**Console shows:**

[image]

I'm using polymer starter kit 2.0.

This modal image opens up on the [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) itself but not when added to my page on localhost. It works in Firefox just fine. I don't know why Chrome says that element is not found.

The page has this structure:

```
<dom-module id="my-testView">
  <template>
   ...

      <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
      <img id="myImg" src="../images/image.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

      <!-- The Modal -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- The Close Button -->
        <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

        <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
      </div>

   ...
 </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-testView'

    });
  </script>

<script>

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</dom-module>
```

And adding  
`window.onload = function(){ CODE HERE }` 
or  
`addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() { CODE HERE }` around this javascript code doesn't help. I don't even know where to put this javascript in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your call in the Polymer element declaration, and this.$ to select an element:

```
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-testView',
    ready: function ()
    {
        var modal = this.$.myModal
        var img = this.$.myImg
        img.onclick = function ( ev )
        {
           //...
        }
    }
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (had to replace * with $ symbol instead in your code) but now it works! You're the best. I wish there would be more people like you